# Can we get the object name using “this” pointer

Tags: c++, gcc, reflection, introspection, libclang

I want to programmatically retrieve the identifier of a C++ class instance at runtime. I'm aware that C++ doesn't support reflection yet, but is there any alternative solution out there? 
For instance, given the following example:

```
class Foo {
  Foo() {
   auto name = reflect::getIdentifierName(this);
   std::cout << name << std::endl;
  }
};

void main() {
   Foo my_obj;
}
```

Executing this program should print out "my_obj".
I'm looking for any utility library that I could use to implement this basic reflection function.

I'm particularly wondering if libclang can be used to extract such information - if so, any hint for how to build the reflect function to do this.

Comment: That is not the class name, that is the identifier of the object. Did you consider giving the name as a string to constructor, storing it and returning it from a getter?

Comment: An object doesn't have a name, a variable does. There isn't a 1:1 relationship between objects and variables, in general.

Comment: I'm looking for a tool that can help programmatically retrieve the name of the class object instance (not the name of the class). Any parser tool for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but this is implementation defined. Proceed at your own risk.

Yunnosch's suggestion sounds much more reasonable without more context.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

class Foo {
public:
  Foo() {
   const char * const name = typeid(this).name();
   std::cout << name << std::endl;
  }
};

int main()
{
   Foo my_obj;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. this solution will output "Foo" which is not "my_obj", I'm looking for a way to print out the class instance variable, not the class name.

Comment: What is this "class instance variable" you speak of? I am not aware of any automatically provided variable, but you can make your own by using a static variable or by just using the this pointer to get the unique address of each object.